# Store API data in subject before subscribing to Observable - Angular 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

I'm trying to store data returned from an API inside a behaviour subject with the next method and I'd like to do this before subscribing  to the observable.

Let's say I have service which has this function to retrieve some data from an API:

```
getData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get(APIURL);
}
```

Now before subscribing to  getData() I'd like to save what has been returned from the API in a subject. I managed to achieve this with the tap() operator, but by reading the documentation, tap should be used for side effects and in this case it doesn't look like one.
So what I did was something like this:

```
getData(): Observable<Data> {
        return this.http.get(APIURL)
               .pipe(tap(data => this.subject.next(data));
}
```

I'm doing this so I can have some sort of cache so that I don't have to call the API again and do some manipulation on that data when it gets updated. For instance let's say I add an element to that data with an update query, now I can update the previous data stored in the subject so everything is up to date. Only by refreshing the page I would call the API again.

What is unclear to me is the use of the tap operator, is it fine to use it like this or are there better alternatives for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly. But if you want to update the data from the API without the subscription, it wouldn't be possible. Angular HttpClient is an unique observable that completes immediately after the first notification. So to keep the front-end updated, you either need to have a timer that continuously polls the back-end on a set interval or look into [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). They are fairly easy to set-up and designed to tackle the exact situation you might be facing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can just check, that you have some data in Subject

```
subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

getData(): Observable<Data> {
   if (subject.getValue()) {
      return of(subject.getValue());
   }
   return this.http.get(APIURL)
        .pipe(tap(data => this.subject.next(data));
}
```

Comment: What is unclear to me is the use of the tap operator, is it fine to use it like this or are there better alternatives for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-angular-cache-demo-qftyr?file=/src/app/http-demo.service.ts) that shows one way to manage your cache request flows in the case where you don't use a state management library.

The essence of the demo is the following

```js
interface IArticle {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class HttpDemoCache {
  // You need a variable where to store the data
  cachedArticleResponse$: BehaviorSubject<IArticle[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  ...
  loadArticles(someQuery) {
  // You need a method that fetches the data from the BE
    this.httpClient.get(...).subscribe((x) => {
      this.cachedArticleResponse$.next(x);
    });
  }

  updateArticles(newArticle: IArticle) {
  // You need a update method to send the new enttity to the back-end + update your cached version
    this.http.post(...., {newArticle}).pipe(
        switchMap(response => 
        this.cachedArticleResponse$
        .pipe(
              take(1),
              tap(cachedArtilces => this.cachedArticleResponse$
              .next([...cachedArticles, newArticle]))
             )
        )
       ).subscribe()    
      });
  }
}
```

Pretty much with this solution you are creating your own state-management solution which responsibility will be to take care of all cahce/fetch/upload/delete logic.

The benefit of this solution is that you have way more control over what is happening than when you are fetching the data directly in the components.

** Side-note: keep in mind that this is a verry brief example of a concept, not a detailed solution.

Comment: Is it ok to subscribe in services? I don't think it's considered good practice in general, but maybe it's the only way?

Comment: As long as you are managing your subscriptions it's ok, you can think about the services in the context of this aproach as a black-box that is taking care for everything and in the outside world (your components or other services) you are just consuming it's api  without fiddling with it's internal.